# MATLAB GUI Table User Input as a letter (or string)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, input

I have a MATLAB GUI uitable (table) where I want the first row to be names and the rest as x y z coordinates.

I have set all zeros initially which is fine. I made it enable for user inputs and its fine when I write a number. However, I want it to 'read' letters as well. (For the first row). Also I will get that matrix data and process it forward.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: By 'FirstRow' you mean that you want to change the column names is that it?

Comment: Yes it is right. Imagine a table like:

Name X Y Z 

Coordinates are numbers therefore they can be easily written to the cells. But when I try to write a letter (a string there) it says displays NaN.